# Python: Use fixture for unittest.TextTestRunner.run()

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Have defined `Cases.py` file with defined suite:

```
import unittest
import pytest

from adminzone_tests.Clients import TestClients

def collect_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestClients)
    return suite

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('admin_session')
def run():
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(collect_suite())

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('client_session')
def run():
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(collect_suite())
```

`conftest.py` file:

```
import pytest

from base.Common import Common
from base.Users import Users


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def admin_session(request):
    Users.users('admin')

    def admin_session_teardown():
        Common.logout()
    request.addfinalizer(admin_session_teardown)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client_session(request):
    Users.users('client')

    def client_session_teardown():
        Common.logout()
    request.addfinalizer(client_session_teardown)
```

Idea: execute the same suite one by one with different user's sessions.
But fixture executes only if has param `autouse=True`

How to make fixture executable without `autouse=True` and run the same suite with different setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution that i was looking for, could be useful for somebody:
Used hook with command line args

`conftest.py` file:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
# adding command line arg --user
parser.addoption('--users', action='append', default=['user1'])

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'users' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        us = set(metafunc.config.option.users)
        if not us:
            us = ['user1']
        elif 'all' in us:
            us = ['user2', 'user1']
        else:
            us = list(us)
        metafunc.parametrize('users', us, scope='session')

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def define_users(request, users):
    # Execute login here, as example called function with param of user_type
    login(users)

def teardown():
    # Execute logout here
    logout()
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
```

`Cases.py` file:

```
import unittest

suite = unittest.TestSuite()

def collect_suite():
    suite.addTest(TestClass1)
    # adding more test classes here

def run():
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Now via command line execute command(in project's root dir)
`python -m pytest Cases.py -s -v -n auto --users all`

Test suite will be executed with login as `user1`, after will be executed with login as `user2`